# .gitignore for various IDEs

Tags: eclipse, vs-code, git, intellij

So I searched almost everywhere for a reasonable `.gitignore` that also covers multiple IDEs while also making it clear which is which. The examples I found so far a poorly structured and do not distinguish between each other.

So far it seems that `.sfdx` is pretty generic and used whenever you're using sfdx in your project it seems while `.vscode` seems to be specific only to VS Code. And I guess `.project` is just Eclipse? (Is anybody still using this?)

I think especially for VS Code I am missing some of the ignores and maybe also missing some generic ones. And under what circumstances are they created?

Here are some more that I found where I'm not quite sure about:

- `.salesforce`
- `.settings`
- `node_modules`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: `.gitignore`s tend to accumulate entries over time and never have them removed; they're kind of cargo-cult files. It is not a bad practice to start with a minimal `.gitignore` in your project, covering only the tools you know and use, and add new entries when you become aware that they're required!

Here's some examples sourced from the `.gitignore` from the [Nonprofit Success Pack](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP), a very long-lived project that has seen many IDEs come and go, as well as a couple of other Salesforce.org projects. NPSP is built using a stack that includes Node.js and Python tools as well.

I've elided some entries that are obsolete or that I cannot explain.

Eclipse is end-of-lifed. You shouldn't have to worry about it anymore - if anyone on your team is still using Eclipse, tell them to stop!

```
.DS_Store                # Cruft from MacOS Finder
Thumbs.db                # Cruft from Windows Explorer

.project                 # I think this is Eclipse but not certain
.settings                # Ditto
salesforce.schema        # Eclipse
Referenced Packages      # Eclipse

build.properties         # Force.com Migration Tool

/IlluminatedCloud        # Illuminated Cloud
.idea/                   # IntelliJ IDEA (Illuminated Cloud)

venv/                    # Python
*.pyc                    # Python

.*.swp                   # Vim

*.sublime-project        # Sublime Text (used with MavensMate)
*.sublime-workspace      # Sublime Text (used with MavensMate)

.sfdx/                   # SFDX

.vscode/                 # Visual Studio Code

.cci/                    # CumulusCI

node_modules/            # Node.js (LWC, Prettier)
coverage/                # LWC coverage information
.localdevserver/         # SFDX/LWC dev
```

Comment: Starting with a minimal `.gitignore` is precisely my intention because some of my colleagues tend to just put so much stuff in there; which of course is mostly never used and nobody even knows why it's there in the first place. That is a great start! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal in Org folder & type `touch .gitignore`
2. It will automatically create a gitignore for saleforce orgs

Or you can copy the following

```
# Salesforce cache
.sf/
.sfdx/
.localdevserver/
deploy-options.json

# LWC VSCode autocomplete
**/lwc/jsconfig.json

# LWC Jest coverage reports
coverage/

# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Dependency directories
node_modules/

# Eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/                


# Windows system files
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
[Dd]esktop.ini
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Local environment variables
.env
```